# Sharing appsettings.json configuration files between different solutions

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have two Visual Studio solutions **SolutionA** and **SolutionB**, each of them containing several web application projects in ASP.NET Core 1.1. The configuration of the projects is handled by the commonly used appsettings.json.

I'd like to outsource some of the config keys that are used in common from the projects of the both solutions, so that the common values don't have to be stored redundantly in both solutions. Is there any way to reach this goal? While I found some way to do it for projects that belong to the same solution (see [Andrew Lock's blog post](https://andrewlock.net/sharing-appsettings-json-configuration-files-between-projects-in-asp-net-core/)), I didn't find any way to do it for projects that are stored in different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you know where your AppSettings.json file is located, you can use the following code:

```
var settingPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(@"../../appsettings.json")); // get absolute path
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile(settingPath, optional:false, reloadOnChange:true);
```

In your project there would be an automaticall reload if the file changes. Hope you're searching for this solution